# push notification FCM - 401 INVALID_KEY or MismatchSenderId postman

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

Code to generate keys : Ps validPublicKey is a firebase code p256dh.

I don´t know where is the problem. If is in the generate code, or the send notification.

I need to put it in php code yet.

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(function(swreg) {
        reg = swreg;
        console.log(swreg.pushManager.getSubscription());    
        console.log(JSON.stringify(swreg.pushManager.getSubscription()));
        return swreg.pushManager.getSubscription();    
    })
    .then(function(sub) {
        if (sub === null) {
            console.log('criando a chave');
            var validPublicKey = 'BIG2EEduGTIoAYMFC3zpq2lksUw-OLRUrq_abhLs1Y2Zbo_xDUGwlozyezbSKqNkYylNN2yWKV5adB0819nQ1y0';
            var convertValidPublicKey = urlBase64ToUint8Array(validPublicKey);                

            return reg.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly:true,
                applicationServerKey:convertValidPublicKey
            });

        } else {
            //we have
        }
    }).then(function(newSub) {                        
        return fetch('https://???????.firebaseio.com/subscriptions.json', {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Accept':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(newSub)
        })
    }).then(function(res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            displayConfirmNotification();
        }            
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

}

[image: errors in the image]